# Convert a text file tree-structured content into a relationship flat dataset

Tags: java, parsing

Given a text file with contents like the following:

```
A.  PRODUCT TYPE [A0001]
    MUTUAL FUNDS [A0002]
        OPEN FUNDED
        CLOSED FUNDS [A1313]
            MONEY FUNDS [A1317]
                INDEX TRACKING [A1318]
                EQUITY TRACKING[A1319]
                SECTOR TRACKING [A1320]
            REGION-SPECIFIC FUNDS [A1325]
            COUNTRY-SPECIFIC FUNDS [A1314]
                AUSTRIA [A1315]
                AUSTRALIA [A1323]
                XXXXX
                XXXXX]
            CXXXXXX [A1321]
            XXXXXXXX [A1324]
        XXXXXXXXX [A1306]
            XXXXX [A1308]
            XXXXX [A1307]
        XXXXXXX [A1309]
            XXXXXX [A1311]
            XXXXXX [A1310]
            XXXXXXX [A1312]
        XXXXXXXXXXX [A1299]
            XXXXXXXX [A1300]
            XXXXXXX [A1301]
        XXXXXXXXXX [A1329]
        XXXXXXXXXX [A1326]
            XXXXXXX [A1327]
            XXXXXXXXXX [A1328]
        XXXXXXXXXXXXX [A1302]
            XXXXXXXXXXX [A1303]
            XXXXXXXXXX [A1304]
    XXXXXXX [A0323]
        XXXXXXXXXX [A0351]
            XXXXXXX [A0362]
            XXXXXXX [A0363]
            XXXXXXXX [A0364]
            XXXXXXX [A0365]
```

What is the recommended method to convert each line of text into something like:

```
PRODUCT TYPE [A0001] > MUTUAL FUNDS [A0002] > CLOSED FUNDS [A1313] > MONEY FUNDS [A1317] >  INDEX TRACKING [A1318]
PRODUCT TYPE [A0001] > MUTUAL FUNDS [A0002] > CLOSED FUNDS [A1313] > MONEY FUNDS [A1317] >  EQUITY TRACKING[A1319]
PRODUCT TYPE [A0001] > MUTUAL FUNDS [A0002] > CLOSED FUNDS [A1313] > MONEY FUNDS [A1317] >  SECTOR TRACKING [A1320]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a POJO to represent each entity in your file. So create a class `ProductType`, a class `Fund` and maybe a class `Tracking` (I do not know your domain, so I do not know the entities or what they mean).
- Then build a parser to parse the text file into the POJOs. You could easily validate that with unit tests (some string in, some object structure out). In your case, you could parse the file line by line and choose the file by determine the tabs/blanks at the beginning of the line.
- When you have the object structure, you could just traverse it and generate what ever you like. You could e.g. use the **visitor pattern** to encapsulate the generation of your final text.